# For what values $(z+1)[x^2-2y^2]-2z^4$ is less or equal to $0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems

Let $L(x)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2$.I have to check that is a Lyapunov function. Clearly $L(x)>0$ (a,b,c>0) and $L(\overline x)=0$. Now I'd like to see for what constants $a,b,c$ I have this $L'(x)\le 0.$

I computed $L'(x)$ and is $L'(x)=(z+1)[x^2-2y^2]-2z^4.$ As you can notice there are not constants anymore, so I think the negativity of $L'(x)$ now depends on $x,y$ and $z$.

What can I do from here to have $L'(x)\le 0?$

Comment: And this is the system $X'=F(X): x'=2yz-xz+2y-x,{}{}{}{}{}{}{} y'=-xz-zy-y-x, z'=-z^3$

Comment: Did you set $a,b,c$ to some values?

Comment: @A.Γ. no, should I set some values?

Comment: Then how do they disappear in $L'$?

Comment: @A.Γ.  yes you're right, I forgot it . I think it was $b=1$. But supposing that I set values to the constants, then what do I do to get  $L'(x)\le 0?$. Can I make a restriction on $x,y$ or $z$?

Comment: If I set $a=c=1$, $b=2$ then I get $L'=2(z+1)(-x^2-2y^2)-2z^4$. If $z+1\ge 0$ then $L'<0$. Note that the last equation $z'=-z^3$ is stable, that is $z$ goes to zero, hence, $z+1$ becomes positive after a while.

Comment: @A.Γ. Why $z'=-z^3$ is stable? I though the term 'stable' was only defined for an equilibrium point. For you, stable variable is when the solution of an equation goes to $0$ when $t\to\infty ?$

Comment: Stability notion can be used for a [system as a whole](https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/lyap.pdf).